# Conditional tags for IE - is it possible NOT to load a JS file if the browser is IE?

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

this might sound weird but instead of adding additional files when the user is on IE 8 I want to remove a JS file that is normally loaded in all other browsers.

So again.

I have this in my in my `head`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="my-script.js"></script>
```

And I want that script to work in all browsers except in IE (because it is not working, so I don't want to load it).

I know the usual conditional tags like this

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<![endif]-->
```

But I guess there is no way to use them the other way around so the only solution that comes to my mind is this …

```
<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') == FALSE) { ?>
      <script type="text/javascript" async src="my-script.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

Is this the best solution for doing this? Moreover I'd actually need to test for all IE Versions below 9. So I don't want the JS file to be loaded in IE8, IE7 and IE6.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**All but IE**

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<script type="text/javascript" async src="my-script.js"></script>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

**Only IE 9 and higher**

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="my-script.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

or

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="my-script.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

**IE 9 and higher + other browsers**

Theoretically, you can use the OR operator, but this is not supported with the NOT IE comment-style.

```
<!--[if !(IE)|(gte IE 9)]>
Test
<![endif]-->
```

You can also use nested comments like this:

```
<!--[if !IE]><![if gte IE 9]>-->
Test
<!--<![endif]><![endif]-->
```

[More information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The first one is no conditional comment, check the syntax again ;)

Comment: — Yes, it is. It just doesn't look like it because it is the hack to reveal code for browsers which don't implement condcom.

Comment: Well for other browsers it's just a regular comment, they don't know about 'conditional comments'. It's the same as writing.

<!-- I like fish -->
<script etc>
<!-- I like cheese also -->

Comment: — For other browsers it is a regular comment, followed by a script element, followed by another regular comment. For IE is a single comment, and the script element won't be processed … which is what the question is asking for.

Comment: I think that's what I meant, maybe I just wasn't very clear. But whatever we call it, it will do what @matt asked :)